# Removing decimals on export python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas to input a list of names and phone numbers, clean that list, then export it. When I export the list, all of the phone numbers have '.0' tacked on to the end. I tried two solutions:
A: round()
B: converting to integer then converting to text (which has worked in the past)

For some reason when I tried A, the decimal still comes out when I export to a text file and when I tried B, I got an unexpected negative ten digit number

Any ideas about what's happening here and/or how to fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have your numbers in `df['phone_numbers']`. You can convert them to int by applying:

```
df['phone_numbers'] = df['phone_numbers'].astype('int')
```

Hopefully that will convert them to int.

Comment: So that's where the fun starts. When I did that, on export the number still had the decimal attached. When I converted to int then converted to string, I got a weird negative number

Comment: @Josh maybe you should show us some of your data and code.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. specified the data type on import with dtype = {"phone" : str, "other_phone" : str})